# Matlab: Index Vector values identical to fixed value

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing

I have a 1-by-1000 vector containing datenums for events, and I want to count total events per date (simplified for this example). The dimensions of `dates` and `events` agree.

My code is

```
   i = 0
   for d = unique(dates)
      i = i + 1
      result(i) = length(events(d == dates))
   end
```

I get a dimension mismatch for `d == dates`. I understand why (`d` is a 1-by-1 vector), but how do I write this properly?

Bonus points: The solution with `i` is pretty ugly... hints?

Thanks!

---

edit by request:
`dates` contains datenums

```
  729028
  729028
  729028
  729028
  729028
```

and `events` contains floats:

```
0.1205
0.2932
2.0384
2.0384
1.0411
0.5425
```

Comment: Edit your question to post example definitions of `dates` and `events`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `unique(dates)` is a column vector, and `for` steps through columns of whatever is on the right-hand side of the equal sign. Thus, `d` is a vector, not a scalar in your original code.

To get the code what you want to do:

```
for d = unique(dates)'
```

To avoid the loop:

```
d = hist(dates,unique(dates));
```

Comment: @LuisMendo: thanks. It's sometimes funny how functions from very different contexts can help solve a problem. `accumarray` can in principle help as well, but if the data isn't integers starting at 1, it gets messy. BTW: only 78 upvotes till Matlab gold! Awesome!

Comment: Yes, I thought of the usual `unique`-`accumarray` couple (which @chappjc is so fond of, BTW), but that requires explicitly indexing the dates. Too messy in this case, as you say. // Hey, I didn't remember about that gold badge... Great! Thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks Jonas for the array issue! Guess what watched this morning... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppfpa5XgZHI&feature=player_detailpage#t=317 . The histogram doesn't work, as the real data is more complex (results has 6 dimensions), but i appreciate the thought!

Answer (score 1):

You only need to compute how many times each value of `dates` is repeated. You can do this with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
uniqueDates = unique(dates);
count = sum(bsxfun(@eq, uniqueDates(:), dates(:).'),2);
```

Each entry of `count` corresponds to the same-index entry of `uniqueDates`.

Example: for `dates = [729028; 729028; 729000; 729028; 729100]` the result is

```
uniqueDates =
      729000
      729028
      729100

count =
     1
     3
     1
```

Comment: Thanks Luis for the idea, unfortunately (my example stripped this fact away) the real data is way too complex for this, and I need to do a few more computations within these loops. Elegant solution!